# Drupal: displaying menus with Views?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I need to develop a kinda Sitemap on the bottom of my website, with all menu items and I was wondering if I can do it with Views.

I actually need to display each main menu item on a different column and add the submenu items to each column.

I realized anyway that Views has not access to Menu items, but only to nodes, or am I wrong ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this with views. It sounds like you just need to have the top level menu "expanded" in menu configuration and style accordingly. For creating something trickier, that involves multiple levels, check out the menu block module (http://drupal.org/project/menu_block).

Comment: I would also recommend the menu block module. It allows you to have all kinds of blocks with entire menus or only sublevels of them. It's very flexible and adds a ton of great features.